# sortable( "toArray" ) not working

Tags: jquery

I am a newbie in terms of AJAX/javascript and am completely helpless, stuck with this issue.

I have a table, that I want to be sortable by drag and drop. I implemented the below mentioned code. This makes the table rows draggable, but im not getting the IDs, that I am supposed to send to the database.

Thanks for your help in advance.

```html
<table id="masterlist" class="table table-striped table-bordered base-style">
  <thead class="bg-grey">
    <tr>
      <th>Field Name</th>
      <th>Created By</th>
      <th>Created On</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tb">
    <tr id="sn_1">
      <td>Doctorate</td>
      <td>User</td>
      <td>15th-Sep-17</td>
      <td>
        Active
        <a href="mypage.php?v=12" class="btn-sm btn-danger">Deactivate</a>
      </td>
      <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_" data-backdrop="false" class="btn-sm btn-warning" role="button">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sn_2">
      <td>Post Graduate/Diploma Degree</td>
      <td>User</td>
      <td>15th-Sep-17</td>
      <td>
        Active
        <a href="mypage.php?v=12" class="btn-sm btn-danger">Deactivate</a>
      </td>
      <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_" data-backdrop="false" class="btn-sm btn-warning" role="button">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sn_3">
      <td>Graduate Degree</td>
      <td>User</td>
      <td>15th-Sep-17</td>
      <td>
        Active
        <a href="mypage.php?v=12" class="btn-sm btn-danger">Deactivate</a>
      </td>
      <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_" data-backdrop="false" class="btn-sm btn-warning" role="button">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Field Name</th>
      <th>Created By</th>
      <th>Created On</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#tb').sortable();
  
  $("#tb").sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      var sortedIDs = $("#tb").sortable("toArray");
      console.log(sortedIDs);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I moved code into a runnable stack snippet in the page and changed alert to `console.log()` (since alert not supported) and it seems to work fine

Comment: I have included some other external scripts too. Can it be a problem?

Comment: Possibly...any errors in browser console? Do note you are initializing `sortable` twice and I left that in. Only need the second one but it won't cause it to fail if order remains the same

Comment: Nopes..Running on chrome

Comment: And it is as shown with script tags below the html? If that script is above then `$("#tb")` won't exist at run time and it needs to be wrapped in a ready event handler

Comment: yes...as shown above

Comment: Not sure what to tell you...can see it running fine right here in the page

Comment: Are you loading another version of jQuery.js with those other scripts? What does happen when you try sorting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159722/discussion-between-penguine-and-charlietfl).

Comment: see...whenevr I run var sortedIDs = $( "#tb" ).sortable( "toArray" ); 
alert(sortedIDs);
it show the alert
Any alert above this line: var sortedIDs = $( "#tb" ).sortable( "toArray" ); works
but any alert below this line wont
I guess...the problem is with this line

Comment: alert is a terrible debugging tool. Use console.log() and check in the browser dev tools console to see the print out

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/01mgv44k/ Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sortable').sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
            $.get('saveSortable.php', {order:newOrder});
        }
    });
});
```